# Recess light not working

Tags: electrical, wiring

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpDWG.jpg)[image]

Installed 6inch can.   2 junction boxes. Left 1 set of 12/3 .Righthand 1 set of 12/2.   Dual 3way switches.  Wires seem fine and switches seem fine except side plastic between black/red wires is cracked.

Hooked up white of light to righthand white in the 14/2.
Hooked up black of light to black of both 14/3 and 14/2.
Hooked up red (switch hot?) To black of light.

Light is constant on, but both switches do not operate on or off functions at all.

Comment: Where do the cables go?

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is confusing.

However, the one thing that stands out is you said you connected the black of the light to BOTH of the blacks in the cable AND the red.

> Hooked up black of light to black of both 14/3 and 14/2. Hooked up red (switch hot?) To black of light.

A device can only be connected to one wire that is either always hot or switched. You have apparently connected the light to all three hot wires in this circuit.

You need to study standard electrical wiring diagrams a little more and check your wiring again.

Good luck!